# how to write Collatz sequence using unfold in scheme/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, collatz

After writing the Collatz sequence generating function the regular way:

```
(define (colatz-seq #;starting@ n)
  (cond ((= n 1) '())
        ((even? n) (cons (/ n 2) (colatz-seq (/ n 2))))
        ((odd? n) (cons (+ (* n 3) 1) (colatz-seq (+ (* n 3) 1))))))
```

I wanted to write it using unfold:

```
(define (next-colatz-step n)
  (cond ((even? n) (/ n 2))
        ((odd? n) (+ (* n 3) 1))))

(define (one? n)
  (= n 1))

(define (colatz-seq #;starting@ n)
  (unfold one? next-colatz-step next-colatz-step n))
```

And it works as expected however i couldn't get it to work without using "next-colatz-step" as both the second and third parameter of unfold. Why?
It seems kinda of odd to provide the same argument to two params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that in both of your solutions you're excluding the starting element in the sequence, and that in the `unfold`-based solution the generated sequence is somehow lagging behind one position, that's why you had to pass `next-colatz-step` twice.

If we start from the given `n` number, the second argument for `unfold` is just the `identity` procedure, which seems more natural. But that leaves us with the problem that the last value (which should always be `1`, assuming that the Collatz conjecture is true) is now missing. That's why now we have to provide an additional procedure for generating the tail of the list. Try this:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (one? n)
  (= n 1))

(define (next-collatz-step n)
  (cond ((even? n) (/ n 2))
        (else (+ (* 3 n) 1))))

(define (last-value n)
  (list n))

(define (collatz-seq n)
  (unfold one? identity next-collatz-step n last-value))

(collatz-seq 10)
=> '(10 5 16 8 4 2 1)
```

Comment: why does: 
    `(define (one n)
      (list 1))`
have n as param even tough it's not used?

Comment: @X10D that's because `unfold` expects a one-arg procedure as its last argument, but we already know that the last value has to be `1`. However, I updated it to use the parameter, at that point in the recursion `n` _is_ `1`.

Comment: One might also write the body of `collatz-seq` as `(unfold one? identity next-collatz-step n list)`.